# Calling Subroutines in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, user-input, subroutine

I can't seem to find any information on subroutines and how to call them in Kotlin. I'm practicing by creating a system which takes input from a user and displays the content prompting the user to say yes if their information is correct, or no if it is not. It then asks them to input "reset" to enter the subroutine until they enter yes.

The code has no errors, but when I get to the "reset" phase, the subroutine is never called and the program just hangs. It allows me to input something else but then just ends the program.

Here is the code below:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("Enter your name")
    val name = readLine()

    println("Enter your email")
    val email = readLine()

    println("Enter your location")
    val location = readLine()

    println("$name $location $email")
    println("Are you sure this is the correct information about you? Type yes or no.")
    val answer = readLine()

    if (answer == "yes") {
        println("Awesome. Details have been saved.")
        return
    } else if (answer == "no") {
        println("Type reset to retry")
        val reset = readLine()
        if (reset == "reset") {
            loop()
        }
    } else {
        println("Error has occurred")
    }
}

fun loop (){
    val answer = readLine()
    while(answer == "no"){
        println("Enter your name")
        val name = readLine()

        println("Enter your email")
        val email = readLine()

        println("Enter your location")
        val location = readLine()

        println("$name $location $email")
        println("Are you sure this is the correct information about you? Type yes or no.")
        if(answer != "yes"){
            println("Awesome. Details have been saved.")
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "The code has no errors" - that's what I always say!

Comment: Friendly advice: set up auto-reformatting in your editor. Bad formatting renders code completely unreadable.

Comment: "The code has no errors, BUT..." so, the code has errors... :D

Comment: Debug your code and you'll find your issue. Hint. Look at the 'answer' variable and how it's used in 'loop'.

Comment: Six months prior I was definitely a lot less knowledgeable about debugging. I will take into consideration the autoreformatting since I wasn't aware of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do while loop can give the effect you want to achieve so try this -

```
fun loop (){
    do {
        println("Enter your name")
        val name = readLine()

        println("Enter your email")
        val email = readLine()

        println("Enter your location")
        val location = readLine()

        println("$name $location $email")
        println("Are you sure this is the correct information about you? Type yes or no.")
        val answer = readLine()

        if(answer == "yes"){
            println("Awesome. Details have been saved.")
            break
        }
    }
    while(answer == "no")
}
```

Comment: This looks like the most promising answer on this; definitely going to give this a try again in Android Studio. Thank you!